# is it possible dedicate a CPU power to a website domain?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I need to know is there a way i can dedicate the CPU power (i have 8 quad core AMD processor), i host over 5 accounts in the Cpanel/WHM,

but there is a one main website i need to dedicate my 50% of the CPU and Memory in case it will be running low on resources when other sites may be eating the mysql and the CPU, the memory ..etc

is this possible ? any dangers in doing this ?

Comment: Your question runs counter to how Unix systems schedule processes -- while you can attempt to outsmart the scheduler and tie processes to specific CPUs this almost always results in reduced performance.  If you want to do the sort of "percent CPU" reservations you're talking about you're probably better off using a virtual machine infrastructure (like VMWare) which can do what you're asking (albeit on a "whole (virtual) machine" level...

Answer (score 1):

You can define a limit for CPU usage per site in Apache using the RLimitCPU Directive